# DokuWiki integration with mantis fails

Tags: integration, wiki, mantis, dokuwiki

I try to integrate dokuwiki with mantis. -> [DokuWiki Integration](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt%3aissue:7075%3aintegration_with_dokuwiki)

I use mantis 1.1.6 and the latests dokuwiki(angua). These applications runs on apache 2.2.14, which is integrated in xampp 1.7.4

My configuration looks like the following:

mantis/config_inc.php and mantis/config_defaults_inc.php:

```
    #####################
# Wiki Integration
#####################

# Wiki Integration Enabled?
$g_wiki_enable = OFF;

# Wiki Engine
$g_wiki_engine = 'dokuwiki';

# Wiki namespace to be used as root for all pages relating to this mantis installation.
$g_wiki_root_namespace = 'mantis';

# URL under which the wiki engine is hosted.  Must be on the same server.
$g_wiki_engine_url = $t_protocol . '://' . $t_host . '/%wiki_engine%/';
```

dokuwiki/conf/local.php:

```
<?php

 define( 'MANTIS_ROOT', 'c:/xampp/htdocs/mantis2/' ); 
 define( 'MANTIS_URL', 'http://localhost/mantis2/' );    


 $conf['useacl']       = 1;               
 $conf['authtype']     = 'mantis';        
 $conf['defaultgroup'] = 'VIEWER';       
 $conf['superuser'] = '@ADMINISTRATOR';   

 require_once( MANTIS_ROOT . 'core.php' );

 ?>
```

Everything else is the same as in the docu descripted.

Now I login with the adminstrator account in mantis. I can see the new menu option "Wiki".
Following this menu option "Wiki" brings me the following error message:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function auth_prepare_username() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dokuwiki\inc\auth\mantis.class.php on line 41

I didn´t modify the mantis.class.php.

Does anybody know what to do now?

Best wishes
Christine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you try a more recent version of MantisBT - 1.1.6 is quite old.